# Click-once deployment utility Throwing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vsto, clickonce

I have an VSTO excel 2007 Add in. For this I have created a Click-once deployment utility. I distributed this various clients who can just double click the .vsto file or set-up.exe and install the add in.
It has worked fine for all clients except one. Clearly it has something to do with the particular client system but as I don't have rights to log in and check my hands are tied.

The exception is shown below. has anyone had a similar situation ? Since the message does not have much info I am a bit stuck.

```
Name:
From : file////C:/ExcelAddin/Adding.vsto
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to 
instance of an Object at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager
.GetManifests(TomeSpan timeout)
at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager
.InstallAddIn()
```

My experience with VSTO clickonce install is not extensive but I know that this is not a VSTO / installer issue but issue with machine or security settings.
FYI all client are local admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved by reinstalling Dot Net framework 3.5 SP1 .